# return KDEplot as a list

Tags: python, signal-processing

im working with signals and am performing KDEplots with sns to visualize how each signal is in comparison to the training signals i have (which can be in two groups and i want to define wether the visualize signal has a density distribution closer to one group or the other) my issue is that even if this visualization is incredibly helpful, i need the kde plot to return a numeric value instead of a visualization, so that i can compute further comparisons with this data. How do i obtain the Kdeplot of a signal as a list or array so that i can work with it instead of just visualizing?

```
wa= abs(s22.walking1[:,2][150:-150])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(8, 8))

# iterate over rows
for r in range(2):
    if r == 0:
        ax[r].set_title("Channel 1")
    else:
        ax[r].set_visible(False)

    # plot density plot for healthy data
    healthy_data = []
    for n in range(1,52):
        if trainid[n-1] == 0:
            data = abs(globals()[f't{n}'].walking1[:,2][150:-150])
            healthy_data.append(data)
    sns.kdeplot(data=np.concatenate(healthy_data), ax=ax[r], color='blue', label='Healthy')

    # plot density plot for unhealthy data
    unhealthy_data = []
    for n in range(1,52):
        if trainid[n-1] == 1:
            data = abs(globals()[f't{n}'].walking1[:,2][150:-150])
            unhealthy_data.append(data)
    sns.kdeplot(data=np.concatenate(unhealthy_data), ax=ax[r], color='orange', label='Unhealthy')
    sns.kdeplot(wa,label='sample',color='green',ax=ax[r])
    ax[r].set_xlabel('Signal Amplitude')
    ax[r].legend()

    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.suptitle('AMPLITUDE DENSITY PLOTS FOR 2ND HALF WALKING SEGMENTS IN CHANNEL 3', y=1.05)
plt.show()
```

the code is irrelevant, all i need to know is how to extract the numerical data from this sns.kdeplots instead of visualizing it

Answer (score 1):

`kdeplot` use `gaussian_kde` from `scipy.stats` module, so you can try to get the numeric results. However the easiest way is to get data from the `Axes` returned by `kdeplot`:

```
ax = sns.kdeplot(...)
x, y = ax.lines[0].get_data()
```